# The Magnet for some people

Tags: riddle

When I was a young adult, I left something at level 2 because
I found something, the thing I found is like a magnet to some people.
Some say it belongs to the castle near the neck and the iron island.
What am I?

Hint 1

> Use the map.

Hint 2

> The answer has some relationship with him. Which person does these pictures represents? [image: enter image description here]+[1]]***+***[image]

Hint 3

> The person I am asking about exists in real. He is not part of any comic book.

If this question remain unsolved until 6-Feb then I'll post the answer myself. And I am sure you'll say "Oh f*k, that was easy."

Comment: I could swear this was posted before, although I can't find it now.

Comment: @DaphneB [This](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4545/can-i-repost-my-deleted-question) will help.

Comment: I just really want this to be about Iron Island from Pokemon.

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre sorry, i didn't knew even Pokemon had iron island. You chose the wrong fiction.

Comment: who is the guy on the second pic? sorry not familiar lol

Comment: @Mekalikot lex luthor...now you need to find what do you get when you  add "Batman vs Superman" movie and "lex luthor" and you will get the hint (not the answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is

> Mark Zuckerberg

**Explanation**

When I was a young adult, I left something at level 2 because

> He left the college at second year.

I found something, the thing I found is like a magnet to some people.

> He is the founder of facebook. Many people are highly addicted to it.

Some say it belongs to the castle near the neck and the iron island.

> The castle near the neck and the iron island is 'The Twin'. The twin brothers claimed that the idea of facebook belonged to them.

Hint 1

> **Use the map.**: Use the map of Game of Thrones which helps in finding the name of the castle.

Hint 2

> **The answer has some relationship with him. Which person does these pictures represents? picture of [Batman v/s Superman + Lex Luthor]**: As dmg correctly guessed, the character of Lex Luthor is played by Jesse Eisenberg who also played the character of Mark Zuckerberg in the movie 'The Social Network'.

If this question remain unsolved until 6-Feb then I'll post the answer myself. And I am sure you'll say "Oh f*k, that was easy."

> Sorry for not giving it as hint but it was also a little hint. Here **f*k = facebook** And also sorry for revealing the answer a day earlier but I don't like puzzles to remain unsolved. One thing I would like to state is that today facebook has completed 12 years. :)

Answer (score 3):

Some say it belongs to the city near the neck and the iron island.

> At the map, Iron Island is at **Ironman's Bay**. So the answer is something which belongs to the Iron Man

When I was a young adult, I left something at level 2 because
I found something, the thing I found is like a magnet to some people.

> **Iron Man's electromagnetic ARC Reactor** keeps the shrapnel reaching to his heart. This may be the reference to the magnet to some people.

Comment: not the iron man. Iron man has nothing to do with that movie in the hint. your answer doesn't explain the line about level 2

Comment: hmm didn't look at hint 2. I will continue thinking then :) other things were closely related so didn't focus

Comment: If u try then try from the new line of thinking coz your answer is not close to the intended answer from any perspective.

Comment: @manshu technically Superman started the super hero boom in 1938 - so no Superman, no Iron Man (though I admit the connection is limited ;)

Answer (score 2):

A little convoluted but my guess is

> Trident

When I was a young adult, I left something at level 2

> Part of maturing into a young adult involves losing your baby teeth. If you're leaving them at level 2, presumably you move to level 3 with teeth i.e, your "tri" "dent".

the thing I found is like a magnet to some people

> A trident was historically used as a polearm or "pole" weapon due to being on the end of a long shaft. A magnet also has poles and can point you in the right direction so could also be a polearm.

Some say it belongs to the city near the neck and the iron island.

> I think this refers to the Trident river in ASOIAF. The city could be Riverrun (?) where the Tullys historically held the position of Lord Paramount of the Trident.

Comment: nice guess...but not the intended answer..

Answer (score 1):

Okay my guess:

> Bizarro

When I was a young adult, I left something at level 2 because

> [There is a young adult book that is reading level 2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0061885169) that is a retelling of the classic comic by the same name. Also, the original origin story was with Superboy not Superman

I found something, the thing I found is like a magnet to some people.

> I would either say this refers to the bonds that actually hold a body together (early versions of Bizarro tended to shatter or had his skin crumble after using too much power or due to exposure to sun/blue kryptonite) or the fact that most of the time he dies he ends up healing someone -twice a blind girl - which would reference love (magnet) or acceptance.

Some say it belongs to the castle near the neck and the iron island.

> In the second of the #2s and the one that references the pictures most directly the new Bizarro comic - [Bizarro #2](http://www.dccomics.com/comics/bizarro-2015/bizarro-2) - has Bizarro invade Iron Heights Prison

What am I?

> This question is echoed in many of these stories of Bizarro in the tradition of Frankenstein's Monster - Am I man, monster, hero, villain, beast!

Hints 1:

> Not sure

Hints 2:

> Several comics have Bizarro created by Lex using Superman's DNA. I'm assuming Batman connection is just based on latest movie but Bizarro #2 shows him dressed as Batman, Jimmy as Robin, and there have been several versions of Bizarro Batman...Batmen?

Comment: a very great guess ..but your answer doesn't explain third sentence and hint 1 which are related to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Ultra wild guess here:

> Jesse W. Reno - the inventor of the escalator.

So let's start from the hints

> The character in the second picture is Lex Luthor, who will be portrayed by **Jesse** Eisenberg in the upcoming movie "Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice"

And now the riddle:

```
When I was a young adult, I left something at level 2 because
```

> He was 29-30 years old when he created the escalator. "Leaving at level two" refers to the function of the escalator.

```
I found something, the thing I found is like a magnet to some people.
```

> People are lazy and they prefer the escalator to the stairs

```
Some say it belongs to the castle near the neck and the iron island.
```

> The very first installation was at Old **Iron** Pier, Coney **Island**, New York City. The castle part refers to the fact that the Old Iron Pier looked like a small castle - [image: Old Iron Pier] and "near the neck" refers to the Hudson river ("neck" means straight/channel).

What am I?

> Jesse W. Reno

Comment: +1 for the right interpretation of the Hint #2..but the answer is wrong.

Comment: Is the name part right?

Comment: no...as i have commented before on this question that that hint doesn't gives you the answer but it has some connection with the answer. I personally think that's what hint should do.